# object oriented jquery - event handlers not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am moving some jquery functions into a javascript object to clean up some code. My problem is, when I put methods on my object's constructor, my event handlers don't seem to respond to events but respond fine if my handlers are *helper methods* and are outside of the object's constructor.

Here's my code that isn't working

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
    this.selectAllHandler();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', this.selectAllHandler);
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    // some code in here
  }
}
```

When using this, my code does not error out and putting `console.log`'s atop the function runs. But when I try to click on the thing to trigger the handler, it doesn't do anything.

But, if I build it as a constructor using a method outside of the object, it works fine. Like this

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', selectAllHandler);
  }
}

function selectAllHandler() {
  // code that works fine
}
```

what am I doing wrong that I cannot call the handlers inside the object's prototype?

**edit**

Here is my new code. The problem now, is `$(this)` seems to refer to the constructor and no longer refers to the element being clicked on.

```
function MyConstructor() {
  this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', this.selectAllHandler.bind(this));
  },
    selectAllHandler: function() {
        var checkboxes = $('.prospect_select_box');

        console.log($(this)); // => [MyConstructor]

        if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            console.log('here')
            checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
            $('#prospect-left-section').hide();
        } else {
            console.log('other here')
            checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
            $('#prospect-left-section').show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML and example call that illustrates the issue?.

Comment: @trincot the code above in the question that's right under `Here's my code that isn't working` is how my code is set up. The only thing that's different now is it's now being called like this: `$(document).on('click', '#my_element', this.selectAllHandler.bind(this));`

Comment: It have read your question, but it does not contain enough info. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pg8q7d6/) --> no problem. So what are you doing?

Comment: @trincot thanks for your answer and I used your code it does work. Now the problem is I am using `$(this)` everywhere (to refer to the object/element being clicked on). It seems `$(this)` now refers to the constructor instead of the element. Is there a fix for that? anything else i need to add to get `$(this)` back to referring to the element and not the constructor?

Comment: This is important information. Could you edit your question and add it?

Comment: @trincot just edited my question

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two objects you are interested in: the constructed object, and the clicked element. The first you need to find the method `selectAllHandler`, the second to work with `$(this)` within that function. Obviously both of them cannot be `this` at the same time, so you'll need to reference one of them in a different way.

Here is how you could do that.

```js
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    var that = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', function () {
      that.selectAllHandler.call(this); 
    });
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    $(this).text('clicked!');
  }
}
  
new MyConstructor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="my_element">click me</button>
```

Note how `call` is used to make sure the `selectAllHandler` will run with `this` set to what jQuery passed on as element.

If however, you need to also reference the constructed object with `this` *inside* `setAllHandler`, then do it the other way around, and use that as `this`, but reference the clicked element via the event object that is passed to the function:

```js
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    var that = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', this.selectAllHandler.bind(this));
  },
  selectAllHandler: function(e) {
    var elem = e.target;
    $(elem).text('clicked ' + this.other);
  },
  other: 'me!'
}
  
new MyConstructor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="my_element">click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer, but unfortunately that does not seem to work

Comment: Updated my answer in light of your updated question.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed answer. very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I also added another variant. Have a look at what best suits your need.